# Print progress bar for a script with real time update

Tags: perl

In my script I check for the existence of elements compared to a set of data that I already have, I do this multiple time, hence the progress bar.

This is what I am doing as of now

```
### A loop which is done multiple times ### 

my $i =1;
my $page = 50;
while ($i <= $page)    
{

##### Part where I print my progress bar ######
print "\rProgress:[";
my $completed =($i/$page)*100;
$completed = ceil($completed);
my $l= $completed;
while ($l>0){
    print "#";
    $l--;
}   
my $remaining = 100-$completed;
while ($remaining>0){
    print " ";
    $m--;
} 
print "] ";
print $completed . "% Complete";


######### Part where I check and keep count #############
foreach (@each_job) 
{
    my $temp = $_;
    # Count number of jobs that exist with my set
    if ($job{"$temp"} == 1) 
    { 
        $does_exist++ ;
        ## print "\n Exists - $does_exist"; #Confused for this print
    }
    else 
    {
        $does_not_exist++;
        ## print "\n Does not exist - $does_not_exist"; #Confused for this print
    };
    };
    $i++;
}
```

So what I currently get is something like

```
Progress:[################################################                                                    ] 48% Complete
```

Which works fine and displays the progress bar as a traverse page by page.
But what I want is something like this -

```
Progress:[################################################                                                    ] 48% Complete
Exists - 3
Does Not Exist - 5
```

Which keeps getting updated at the same spot (using `\r`). 
Can someone help me ?

Comment: What is your OS and terminal type? For Unix you'll want to check out a termcap module like `Term::Cap` or find the character sequences to move your cursor up yourself.

Comment: If you want to re-invent the wheel (you shouldn't) see the `SCP` and `RCP` [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: @Mob, I am using a Mac OS and Iterm 2 as terminal type.

Comment: @Elpaco, I am actually trying to reinvent the wheel. this obviously is not necessary, but just took it up as a programming challenge. Thanks to ur advice the SaveCursor and RestoreCursor would make a lotta sense. Wondering if you would know the codes? I tried `\x1B7`for save and `\x1B8` for restore. But they dint work

Comment: @seleniumnewbie: try it as a string instead `"\033[s"` and `"\033[u"` (`\033` + `[` is the `CSI` code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a curses library which handles all the escape code rigamarole for you, and lets you get down to just updating regions of the screen.

Start with this [CPAN search for curses modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=curses).

Comment: So which one do u suggest? and will the implementation be using save and restore cursor position?

Comment: Curses is a standardized set of cursor control commands. The rest is up to you.